# Java Text editor - How to create New File

Tags: java

I followed this tutorial on how to create a simple text editor in Java, but the person who wrote the tutorial seems to have left out how to create a new file http://forum.codecall.net/topic/49721-simple-text-editor/

For the most part I was able to follow the guide, but I have no idea how one would create the 'New File' functionality.

Comment: How do you think it should be done? What happens when you try to implement it?

Comment: `Action New = new AbstractAction("New", new ImageIcon("new.gif")) {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   File file = new File("Untitled.txt");
 };`

is all I could come up with. Not really sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

you can write code like this to create new file :

```
try {

      File file = new File("c:\\newfile.txt");

      if (file.createNewFile()){
        System.out.println("File is created!");
      }else{
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: In a text editor, you don't write the file until the user left clicks on the "Save As..." button or menu option.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the save button on your text editor, include this in your actionPerformed() method -

```
FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(f1,"Save Your File",FileDialog.SAVE);
fd.setSize(400,200);
fd.setVisible(true);
try 
{
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(fd.getDirectory()+fd.getFile());
fw.write(t1.getText()); // t1 is the name of your textarea
fw.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```